# iOS forge run dont work on Trigger.io - Error: dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: xcode, trigger.io

I tried to run a iOS "Hello World" sample on trigger.io and received this error:

```
[INFO] dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient
[INFO]   Referenced from: /Users/forge-workspace/personal/.template/lib/ios-sim-xc4.3
[INFO]   Reason: image not found
```

I'm on Maverick OS, and have the latest tools (xcode 5.1).

tks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In today's release (v2.1.4), they added support for Xcode 5.1.
If you **upgrade your project's** platform version to **2.1.4** you should be good to go.